# Http2 protocol and status messages

Tags: http, http-status-codes

So i just found out the hard way that the http2 protocol does not support http status messages like 404 **Not Found** in the old http1.1 protocol. 
One of our web Api's is using the http status message to return a readable message to the end user.

Now my question is, is there a new way of returning status messages in http2 or do we have to return the message in the http response body?

Comment: Wasn't aware of that and for a second I read that as the status code (404) was not returned rather than status message ("Not found") and was very confused! Anyway couldn't you just add a lookup to your api? Would also have the added benefit of returning the same message for each code rather than depending on each web servers implementation (do they all return the exact same status message for each code?).

Comment: @BarryPollard, over time, 404 changed from _Page Not Found_ into just _Not Found_. Some servers will put a word there that better reflect the type of content, for example _Image Not Found_ or _User Not Found_...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no new standard way, thus either a custom response header or the message body are your only choices.

(For the record: I argued against this change)

Comment: From my perspective, this should not be much of a change. Because the RFC from 1.1 states that the reason phrases listed there are only recommendations and that the client is not required to examine them, I always looked at reason phrases as optional and tried to not depend on them.