# How can I get Reason-Phrase from JDK9/HttpResponse?

Tags: http2, java-9

I'm writing a client library for HTTP.

With [HttpResponse](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/net/http/HttpResponse.html), how can I get `Reason-Phrase` value?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567489/http2-protocol-and-status-messages

Comment: @sbordet Thanks. Wow, I've never known that http/2 removed Reason-Phrase. https://evertpot.com/http-2-finalized/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest anyone came with the same curiosity to take a look at

https://evertpot.com/http-2-finalized/

> HTTP/2 does away with the ‘reason phrase’. In HTTP/1.1 it was possible for servers to submit a human readable reason along with the status code, such as `HTTP/1.1 404 Can't find it anywhere!`. Or `HTTP/1.1 200 I like pebbles`, but in HTTP/2 this is removed.